# Accessing & Reverting to Specific (preferablyNamed) Revision via Appscript in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I'm not finding a way to interact with 'Named' versions of a Google Sheet using the Drive Rest Revisions methods. Or to move a specific revision to the head.

I'm trying to sort out how to move a named revision to the head after an editor makes edits and finishes. Upon a finish trigger, I want the script to (among other things) reset the sheet to the specific named revision for the next user. (ideally) or, assuming there's no support for named version, to move the specific Revision to the head by RevisionID.

I've only played around with the 'Try it' feature on Google's Reference page for the various Revisions methods and have not found a way there to move a revision to the head or interact in any way with revisions by Version Name.

Comment: This is an interesting problem. What is your use case?

Comment: According to the [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/update), we can update only publishing options and not all of them are for sheets. There is no option to make a revision as "head".

Comment: @J.G. - The hope is to use a google sheet as a recurrent order form with a 'Base' template revision with all constant data / available line items / costs in place and editable variable data like quantities/ date/ PO# etc.  So the user could open the sheet, enter the specific order data, run a submit script and the script would name that revision in the history and set the base template back as the head revision for the next time.

Comment: What I would probably do is write a script that makes them a fresh copy of the gsheet for their version. You could add a table of contents page to the base copy that gets updated with the locations of each form.  Another option would be to copy the base tab and use a new tab per order (not an indefinite solution).