# List and copy a specific named version of a Google Sheets file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, version-control, google-drive-api, revision-history

Right now I am using this code to create a copy of a specific Spreadsheet.

```
var fileToCopyID = "...";
var destinationFolderID = "...";

// get the root folder
var destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderID);

// get the file
var fileToCopy = DriveApp.getFileById(fileToCopyID);

// create the file
return fileToCopy.makeCopy("new", destinationFolder);
```

Is there a way to copy a specific named version of the Spreadsheet? I checked all of the documentation at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ but there doesn't seem to be anything that speaks to named versions.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Sorry! I had a typo earlier. I fixed. Is there a way to copy a specific named version of the Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think so. Google Drive API has the [Revisions resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) but I did't find a method to get a named version or the revision name either.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script
- https://developers.google.com/drive
- https://developers.google.com/sheets

Related questions

- [Save & access "named version" of Google Sheet via GAS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55926555/1595451)
- [Drive API v3 restore previous version of file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40203239/1595451)
- [Accessing & Reverting to Specific (preferablyNamed) Revision via Appscript in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55818978/1595451)
  This is basically the same question but it hasn't any answer yet.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully they will add a way soon. Would make managing draft versions of template files easier.